# Why does my vector splits in two vectors?

Tags: javascript, canvas, vector

I'll try to explain as best I can.

I'm using canvas, and a basic vectors library I wrote in JS. Now my enemy object has a few vectors in it, the math seems right all the way through, but I end up seeing the enemy's weapon split into two and fire in both directions when I get too close to it.

[Not close](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRJzd.jpg)
[Close](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4ucw.jpg)

The player is the white circle with a green dot in the middle, and I use mousemove for the coordinates.

After looking at the images, I noticed that it creates two weapons that fire at the correct fireRate, one after the other. It doesn't show in the images, but when you look at it in the browser, there are two small red dots firing those yellow projectiles.

I looked over the code, and I can't find anything repeating itself that could cause the dot to split into two, and I started to wonder if it has anything to do with Math.atan2() or maybe something else.

Here's the enemy function:

```
function Enemy(enemyConfig){
    this.enemyConfig = enemyConfig;
    this.position = new Vector(enemyConfig.x, enemyConfig.y);
    if(this.enemyConfig.hasVelocity){
        this.velocity = new Vector(enemyConfig.vx, enemyConfig.vy);
    }
    this.radius = enemyConfig.radius;
    this.hasWeapon = false;
    if(enemyConfig.hasWeapon){
        this.weaponId = enemyConfig.weaponId;
        this.projectiles = [];
        this.weapon = this.position.Copy();
        this.weaponDistanceFromPosition = this.radius * .9;
        this.weaponAngleToPlayer = 0;
        this.weaponReloaded = true;
        this.fireRate = enemyConfig.fireRate || .25;
        this.reloadTimer = this.fireRate;

        this.hasWeapon = true;
    }
    this.target = cfg.player;
};

Enemy.prototype.Draw = function(){
    cfg.ctx.save();
    cfg.ctx.beginPath();
    cfg.ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)";
    cfg.ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)";
    cfg.ctx.arc(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.radius, 0, PI*2, false);
    cfg.ctx.fill();
    cfg.ctx.stroke();
    cfg.ctx.closePath();
    cfg.ctx.restore();
    
    if(this.hasWeapon){
        cfg.ctx.save();
        cfg.ctx.beginPath();
        cfg.ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)";
        // cfg.ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)";
        cfg.ctx.arc(this.weapon.x, this.weapon.y, 2, 0, PI*2, false);
        cfg.ctx.fill();
        // cfg.ctx.stroke();
        cfg.ctx.closePath();
        cfg.ctx.restore();

        if(this.projectiles.length > 0 && this.projectiles){
            this.projectiles.forEach((projectile, index, projectiles) => {
                if(projectile.exists) projectile.Draw();
            })
        }
    }
};

Enemy.prototype.Update = function(){
    if(this.hasWeapon){
        this.weaponAngleToPlayer = this.weapon.AngleTo(this.target.position);
        this.weapon.Length = this.weaponDistanceFromPosition;
        this.weapon.Angle = this.weaponAngleToPlayer;
        this.weapon.AddTo(this.position);

        this.weaponReloaded = (this.reloadTimer === 0);
        if(!this.weaponReloaded){
            this.reloadTimer -= Math.min(cfg.deltaTime / 1000, this.reloadTimer);
        }else{
            this.FireWeapon();
        }

        if(this.projectiles.length > 0){
            this.projectiles.forEach((projectile, index, projectiles) => {
                projectile.Update();
                if(!projectile.exists) projectiles.splice(index, 1);
            });
        }
    }
    // console.log(this.projectiles);


    // this.target = cfg.player;
    // console.log(this.target.position);

};

Enemy.prototype.FireWeapon = function(){
    var projectile = new Projectile();
    projectile.position = this.weapon.Copy();
    projectile.velocity = this.weapon.Copy();
    projectile.velocity.Angle = this.weaponAngleToPlayer;
    projectile.velocity.Limit(15);
    projectile.exists = true;

    this.projectiles.push(projectile);
        
    this.reloadTimer = this.fireRate;
};
```

```js
var PI = Math.PI;
var cfg = cfg || {};
var player;

cfg.expectedFPS = 60;
cfg.framesPerMs = cfg.expectedFPS / 1000;
cfg.deltaTime = 0;
cfg.previousTimeStamp = undefined;
cfg.direction = {
    up: 1.5 * PI,
    down: .5 * PI,
    left: PI,
    right: 0
};
cfg.mouse = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    radius: 2
};
cfg.projectiles = [];
cfg.player = null;
cfg.enemies = [];

function random(min, max = null){
    if(max != null){
        return Math.random() * (Math.max(min, max) - Math.min(min, max)) + Math.min(min, max);
    }
    return Math.random() * min;
};

function Background(config = {}){
    var config = config;
    cfg.ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)";
    cfg.ctx.fillRect(0, 0, cfg.canvas.width, cfg.canvas.height);
};

function KeepInCanvas(object){
    if(object.position.x + object.radius >= cfg.canvas.width)
        object.position.x = cfg.canvas.width - object.radius;
    if(object.position.x - object.radius <= 0)
        object.position.x = object.radius;
    if(object.position.y + object.radius >= cfg.canvas.height)
        object.position.y = cfg.canvas.height - object.radius;
    if(object.position.y - object.radius <= 0)
        object.position.y = object.radius;
};

function IsOutOfCanvas(object){
    return (object.position.x + object.radius < 0 || object.position.x - object.radius > cfg.canvas.width
        || object.position.y + object.radius < 0 || object.position.y - object.radius > cfg.canvas.height);
};

function Vector(x = 0, y = 0){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
};

Vector.prototype = {
    get Length(){
        return Math.sqrt(this.x * this.x + this.y * this.y);
    },
    set Length(length){
        var angle = this.Angle;
        this.x = Math.cos(angle) * length;
        this.y = Math.sin(angle) * length;
    },

    get Angle(){
        return Math.atan2(this.y, this.x);
    },
    set Angle(angle){
        var length = this.Length;
        this.x = Math.cos(angle) * length;
        this.y = Math.sin(angle) * length;
    },

    Add: function(vector){ return new Vector(this.x + vector.x, this.y + vector.y); },    
    AddTo: function(vector){
        this.x += vector.x;
        this.y += vector.y;
    },

    Subtract: function(vector){ return new Vector(this.x - vector.x, this.y - vector.y); },
    SubtractFrom: function(vector){
        this.x -= vector.x;
        this.y -= vector.y;
    },

    Multiply: function(factor){ return new Vector(this.x * factor, this.y * factor); },
    MultiplyBy: function(factor){
        this.x *= factor;
        this.y *= factor;
    },

    DivideBy: function(factor){
        this.x /= factor;
        this.y /= factor;
    },

    AngleTo: function(vector){
        return Math.atan2(vector.y - this.y, vector.x - this.x);
    },

    Copy: function(){ return new Vector(this.x, this.y); },

    Normalize: function(arg = false){
        if(this.Length > 0){
            if(arg) return this.Divide(this.Length);
            this.DivideBy(this.Length);
        }
    },

    Limit: function(factor){
        if(this.Length > factor){
            this.Normalize();
            this.MultiplyBy(factor);
        }
    }
};

function Player(){
    this.position = new Vector(0, 0);
    this.radius = 20;
};

Player.prototype.Draw = function(){
    cfg.ctx.save();
    cfg.ctx.beginPath();
    cfg.ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 180, 0, .35)";
    cfg.ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)";
    cfg.ctx.arc(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.radius, 0, PI*2, false);
    cfg.ctx.fill();
    cfg.ctx.stroke();
    cfg.ctx.closePath();
    cfg.ctx.restore();
};

Player.prototype.Update = function(){
    this.position.x = cfg.mouse.x;
    this.position.y = cfg.mouse.y;
    KeepInCanvas(this);
};

function Projectile(){
    this.position = new Vector(0, 0);
    this.velocity;
    this.radius = 5;
    this.exists = false;
};

Projectile.prototype.SetInitialVelocity = function(angle, length){
    var x = Math.cos(angle) * length,
        y = Math.sin(angle) * length;
    return new Vector(x, y);
};

Projectile.prototype.Draw = function(){
    cfg.ctx.save();
    cfg.ctx.beginPath();
    cfg.ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 160, 0, 1)";
    cfg.ctx.arc(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.radius, 0, PI*2, false);
    cfg.ctx.fill();
    cfg.ctx.closePath();
    cfg.ctx.restore();
};

Projectile.prototype.Update = function(){
    this.position.AddTo(this.velocity.Multiply(cfg.framesPerMs).Multiply(cfg.deltaTime));
    if(IsOutOfCanvas(this)) this.exists = false;
};
function Enemy(enemyConfig){
    this.position = new Vector(enemyConfig.x, enemyConfig.y);
    this.radius = enemyConfig.radius;
    this.hasWeapon = false;
    if(enemyConfig.hasWeapon){
        this.projectiles = [];
        this.weapon = this.position.Copy();
        this.weaponAngleToPlayer;// = 0;
        this.hasWeapon = true;
    }
    this.target = cfg.player;
};

Enemy.prototype.Draw = function(){
    cfg.ctx.save();
    cfg.ctx.beginPath();
    cfg.ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)";
    cfg.ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)";
    cfg.ctx.arc(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.radius, 0, PI*2, false);
    cfg.ctx.fill();
    cfg.ctx.stroke();
    cfg.ctx.closePath();
    cfg.ctx.restore();
    
    if(this.hasWeapon){
        cfg.ctx.save();
        cfg.ctx.beginPath();
        cfg.ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)";
        cfg.ctx.arc(this.weapon.x, this.weapon.y, 2, 0, PI*2, false);
        cfg.ctx.fill();
        cfg.ctx.closePath();
        cfg.ctx.restore();

        if(this.projectiles.length > 0 && this.projectiles){
            this.projectiles.forEach(projectile => {
                if(projectile.exists) projectile.Draw();
            })
        }
    }
};

Enemy.prototype.Update = function(){
    if(this.hasWeapon){
        this.weaponAngleToPlayer = this.position.AngleTo(this.target.position);
        // console.trace(this.weaponAngleToPlayer);
        this.weapon.Length = this.radius * .9;
        this.weapon.Angle = this.weaponAngleToPlayer;
        this.weapon.AddTo(this.position);
        
        this.FireWeapon();

        if(this.projectiles.length > 0){
            this.projectiles.forEach((projectile, index, projectiles) => {
                projectile.Update();
                if(!projectile.exists) projectiles.splice(index, 1);
            });
        }
    }
};

Enemy.prototype.FireWeapon = function(){
    var projectile = new Projectile();
    projectile.position = this.weapon.Copy();
    projectile.velocity = projectile.position.Copy();
    projectile.velocity.Angle = this.weaponAngleToPlayer;
    projectile.velocity.Limit(15);
    projectile.exists = true;
    // console.trace(projectile);
    this.projectiles.push(projectile);
};
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Space Shooter</title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="gameCanvas"></canvas>
    <script>        
        window.onload = function(){
            cfg.canvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
            cfg.canvas.focus();
            cfg.canvas.width = 760;
            cfg.canvas.height = 1060;
            cfg.canvas.style.cursor = "none";
            cfg.ctx = cfg.canvas.getContext("2d");
            cfg.canvasOffset = cfg.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
            
            cfg.player = player = new Player();
            cfg.enemies[0] = new Enemy({
                x: 200,
                y: 500,
                radius: 35,
                hasWeapon: true
            });
            cfg.enemies[1] = new Enemy({
                x: 500,
                y: 200,
                radius: 45,
                hasWeapon: true
            });

            window.requestAnimationFrame(Game);
        };

        window.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e){
            cfg.mouse.x = e.clientX - cfg.canvasOffset.x;
            cfg.mouse.y = e.clientY - cfg.canvasOffset.y;
        });
            
        function Game(timestamp){
            if(!cfg.previousTimeStamp) cfg.previousTimeStamp = timestamp;
            cfg.deltaTime = timestamp - cfg.previousTimeStamp;
            cfg.previousTimeStamp = timestamp;
            Update();
            Draw();
            window.requestAnimationFrame(Game);
        };

        function Update(){
            player.Update();

            if(cfg.enemies.length > 0){
                cfg.enemies.forEach(enemy => {
                    enemy.Update();
                });
            }
        };

        function Draw(){
            Background();

            if(cfg.enemies.length > 0){
                cfg.enemies.forEach(enemy => {
                    enemy.Draw();
                });
            }

            player.Draw();
        };
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: There is nothing obviously wrong in what you shown, but there is obviously not enough to produce a [mcve]. To help you debug the issue, you could add some `console.trace()` calls to double check that you don't have multiple instances of the same *Enemy*. If this doesn't help, start removing some unnecessary logic (e.g replace the player with a static object, replace all that can be with constants, etc.) until you find the culprit. If at this stage you still haven't found a way around, come back here with what would now be a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Found the issue, it was in this line of code: `this.weaponAngleToPlayer = this.**weapon**.AngleTo(this.target.position);` Changed it to `this.position.AngleTo`. But I find it confusing a bit because this.weapon is a `new Vector(this,position)`, I'm guessing it was calculating the angle twice and because I was adding an extra position to move away from the center of this.position afterwards. Strange, I'll post a snippet of the working code.